# How to reduce white space between lines in table of figures?

Tags: tables, floats

I have this table of figures:

```
\begin{figure}[th!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{Radcliffe Cam}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l XXXX }
&Original & WI & \multicolumn{2}{c}{TPWI} \\  \addlinespace[2pt]   
\rothead{Rogue One: A Star Wars Story}        &
\includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{Figures/original_rogue_one.jpg}
                        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{Figures/IMG_4678.jpg}    
                        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{Figures/IMG_4669.jpg}    
                        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{Figures/IMG_20170120_115803.jpg}\\  \addlinespace[2pt]    
\rothead{Split}         &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{Figures/original_split.jpg}
                        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{Figures/IMG_20170120_111446.jpg}
                        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{Figures/IMG_5090.jpg}
                        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{Figures/IMG_4738.jpg}\\  \addlinespace[2pt]

\rothead{Bacchus}        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{Figures/original_bacco-caravaggio.jpg}    
                        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{Figures/IMG_9965.jpg}
                        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{Figures/IMG_20170112_164436.jpg}
                        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{Figures/IMG_20170524_175644.jpg}\\  \addlinespace[2pt]
\rothead{The Birth of Venus}        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{Figures/original_nascita_di_venere-sandro_botticelli.jpg}    
                        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{Figures/IMG_20170112_111245.jpg}
                        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{Figures/IMG_8864.jpg}
                        &   \includegraphics[width=\hsize,valign=m]{Figures/IMG_20170524_131835.jpg}\\  \addlinespace[2pt]

\end{tabularx}
    \caption{Instances from the movie and poster dataset. The leftmost column are the original instances. The second column are good quality WI. The two right most columns are TPWI images.}
\label{fig:samples}
\end{figure}
```

And this is how it looks like in a 2 column document:

[image]

As you can see, there is a large white space in the last row. Similarly, this happens in another table which follow the same format described above. How can I remove it to save space?

Comment: it's not clear why the space is there (without a test file to run) but `\\[-10pt]` at the end of the tabular row should make it go.

Comment: I'd never use tabularx for this (as there is no line breaking within the cells) I'd use tabular (and c columns)

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and have a look at Images there.

Comment: The code snippet you've posted so far, augmented by some reasonable [?] assumptions about the document class and other page parameters that are in use in order to make the code compilable, does not give rise to the issue you're encountering. Please augment your code so that it does give rise to the issue you wish to fix. E.g., post information about the document class that's in use, the packages you load, the page size and textblock size parameters, and the font(s). Do also reveal how `\rothead` and `\rotheadsize` are defined, please.

Comment: @Mico: They're defined by the `makecell` package.